# C++ change member type in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have a class Base1 that contains an array of objects of a different class Base2. I would like to have a derived class Derived1 that inherits everything from Base1 except the array is of type Derived2 (which is a derived class of Base2). For example, something like this:

```
class Base2{
        int a2;
};

class Derived2: public Base2{
        int b2;
};

class Base1{
        Base2* list;
};

class Derived1: public Base1{
        Derived2* list;
};
```

My understanding is that in the above example, an object of Derived1 would actually have TWO arrays:

```
list
```

and

```
Base1::list
```

which I don't want.

The idea is that all the functionality of Base1 should still work for a Derived1 object since Derived2 "is a" Base2. It would be really dirty, but I guess I could just delete[] the Base1::list array in the Derived1 constructor.

Does anyone see a solution to this? It seems like something that would happen frequently, and I cannot believe a simple solution does not exist. Would using templates work? My thought was no, since all the functionality in Base1 and Derived1 need to know that they are dealing with Base2 and Derived2 objects, respectively.

Comment: Rather than inheritance you should use templates, IMO

Comment: In what way is `Derived1` a `Base1`? You need some sort of interface to the class for it to make sense, and without that interface we can't suggest alternatives. Could you give an example of how a `Base1` would be used?

Comment: Do you intend to use these types polymorphically?

Comment: @onof: Judging by the question, it's too early to start about templates.

Comment: A `Derived2` is a `Base2`, but an *array* of `Derived2` is not an array of `Base2`, and if `Derived1` tries to use `Base1` methods that rely on `Base2*` pointer arithmetic, you'll have problems. (Lousy names, by the way.)

Comment: If this worked the way you want it to, and you had a Derived1 and called a Base1 method on it, from Base1's perspective it's perfectly valid to put *anything* derived from Base2 in the array even though the array itself is only capable of storing pointers to Derived2's.

Comment: @qid: that is exactly what I want. The problem is how to get Derived1 to store Derived2's in the same list.

Comment: @Carl : The question is why does `Derived1` _care_ that it's `Derived2*`s in `list` rather than `Base2*`s? If you use inheritance _properly_, `list` can be of type `Base2*` and contain instances of `Derived2*`, and whatever special behavior you need from `Derived2` can be accessed by calling virtual member functions defined in `Base2` and subsequently overridden in `Derived2`.

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect to happen when someone downcasts a `Derived1` class to `Base1`? It will crash when `list` is used after you sabotage the base class. The best thing is to continue to use the base class's `list`, and make sure only objects of type `Derived2` are put in the list. If the content of the list can't be externally modified, that would work and be safe.

Yes, I know there's a lot more to say about this but let's take it one step at a time.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do, in general case, seems dangereous, but I assume you know the risks ;)

I can suggest two solutions:

**Option 1:**

You can hide the actual pointer in a `protected` section and provide an access function.

```
class Base1 {
    protected:
    void *ptr
    public:
    Base2 *list() {return (Base2*)ptr;}
};

class Derived1 : public Base1 {
    public:
    Derived2 *list() {return (Derived2*)ptr;}
};
```

Basically, the `Base2::list` will be hidden by the `Derived2::list`. Note, you cannot make them virtual and benefit from the virtuality. The return type has to be known at compile-time.

**Option 2:**

You can use templated base class.

```
template <typename T>
class List {
    public:
    T *list
    //implement all functionality which is common, regardless of the type T
};

class Base1 : public List<Base2> {
    //specifics for Base2 type
};

class Derived1 : public List<Derived2> {
    //specifics for Derived2
};
```

Note that in this construct, Base1 and Derived1 are not directly related, but have a common ancestor instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the array of Base2 from Base1, and create a new class with the list:

```
class Base2{
        int a2;
};

class Derived2: public Base2{
        int b2;
};

class Base1{
};

class Base1WithList : public Base1{
        Base2* list;
};

class Derived1: public Base1{
        Derived2* list;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there exists anything simple that solves your problem.

I would have used one of the following ways -

**OPTION 1** 
Hide the Base2* list (in base1 class) by making it private, and save it getting inherited by the derived class (derived1). And of course, define a getter function in base1 class to access the list.

**OPTION 2** 
Just change the type of list in base1 class to (a pointer to) Derived2 , and rely on the fact that a pointer to a derived class is type-compatible with a pointer to its base class.

**OPTION 3** 
Forget inheritance and use templates. You will just need to specify the type (Base2* or Derived2*) while instantiating an object, and life will be beautiful again.

Answer (score 0):

The [question comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512826/c-change-member-type-in-derived-class#comment7666215_6512826) from @ildjarn gave me the solution to a similar problem:

```
class Base {
    Base* children;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int answer;
   public:
    void give_answer() {
        this->answer == 42;
        for(auto child : this->children) {
            // at this point `give_answer` is not defined for items of `children`
            child->give_answer();  // -> error: ‘class Base’ has no member named ‘give_answer’
        }
    };
};
```

The solution is to introduce a virtual function into `Base`:

```cpp
class Base {
    Base* children;
   public:
    virtual void give_answer();
}
```

`virtual void give_answer() = 0;` would also work, making `Base` abstract.

(This example is a bit contrived, because why even have `Base`, but in my use case `Derived` is actually  `Derived<T>`, and `Base` is a whole tree implementation.)